# Overlay DOM element on video

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, canvas

Is there a method to place a DOM element over particular coordinates of particular video frames using Web technology? I am trying to float a picture of my face over the face of an actor in a video.

Any tips or suggestions or algorithms would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what time (in milliseconds) you want to place the object, then yes. You can set a timer to check the video's current time position using [`video.currentTime()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#media-controller-position), and then place objects on the video by absolute positioning.

```
var objects = {
    [
        object: $("<div></div>").addClass("myObject"),
        timeShow: 3;
        timeHide: 9;
    ]
};

var myVideo = document.getElementById('myPlayer');
var currentTime = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    currentTime = myVideo.currentTime();

    for(var i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
        if(objects[i].timeShow > currentTime && objects[i].timeEnd < currentTime)
            objects[i].object.show();
    }
}, 1000); // loops at 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position:absolute` and set `top` and `left` CSS properties.

Something like this:

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative">
   <video element />
   <div id="blocker" style="width:100px; height:100px; position: absolute; top:240px; left:140px; background:yellow">
   </div>
</div>
```

So the "blocker" div will span 100px by 100px and be located at 240px from top and 140px left from the top left of the "container" div.

Answer (score 0):

use absolute positioning `position: absolute;` (css) to get something in a set position. Note that you might need to use `z-index` (css) to overlay one item with another.

Just so you know: its pretty much impossible to track a face in a running video and putting a moving `<div>` on top of it. Not sure what you are trying to achieve :p